# Dose of folinic acid/5MTHF equivalent to 400 mcg folic acid?

Tags: micronutrients, metabolism, folate

We know that the recommended daily dose of folic acid is 400 mcg/day. What would be the equivalent daily doses of folinic acid and of 5MTHF, if a person would decide to substitute folic acid with them?

I mean, what would be the dose of folinic acid or 5MTHF with a vitamin activity similar to that of 400 mcg of folic acid? What are the conversion coefficients?

I can see two downvotes for "lacking prior research", but that is just untrue. I googled to find the answer using all word combinations I could come up with. Try googling and you'll soon discover that it's not easy to get the answer. I haven't managed to find it.